# NodeBB with Nginx - "This web page has a redirect loop"

Tags: nginx, nodebb

I'm trying to set up NodeBB at `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nodebb`. I have the following settings for Nginx and NodeBB:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/nodebb.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location /nodebb/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

/usr/share/nginx/nodebb/config.json

```
{
    "base_url": "http://`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "port": "4567",
    "secret": "xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx",
    "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "database": "mongo",
    "mongo": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "27017",
        "username": "xxxxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "database": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    "bcrypt_rounds": 12,
    "upload_path": "/public/uploads",
    "use_port": false,
    "relative_path": "/nodebb"
}
```

When I navigate to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nodebb` I get redirected to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nodebb/404` with a browser error message `This web page has a redirect loop`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Just to say that if I navigate to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4567/nodebb/` - it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Set your server name to the same as your base_url, not localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Set `server_name` to `yourdomain.com` in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nodebb.conf and the `base_url` to `http://127.0.0.1` in /usr/share/nginx/nodebb/config.json.

> If you do this you will not be able to open the nodebb site on http://yourdomain.com:4567, but on http://yourdomain.com or http://yourdomain.com:80 (which is the default port).